# Найти разницу в столбцах в двух DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть два DataFrame с большим количеством столбцов. Нужно узнать, какие НЕ встречаются одновременно в обоих.

Пример:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3],'y': [1,2,3],'z': [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3],'y': [1,2,3]})
```

Ожидаемый результат: столбец `z`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [set.symmetric_difference()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
In [24]: set(df1).symmetric_difference(set(df2))
Out[24]: {'z'}
```

или, используя Pandas:

```
In [25]: df1.columns.symmetric_difference(df2.columns)
Out[25]: Index(['z'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Откуда ты все это знаешь?)

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!